# Apache https reverse proxy with Tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat, redirect, https, proxy

Well, I looked everywhere I could, but if some know where I could find a solution, sorry for asking once again the question.

We are looking to implement this solution : 
HTTP client -> Apache 2.4 Reverse Proxy -> HTTP Server => Works OK
HTTPS client -> Apache 2.4 Reverse Proxy -> HTTPS Server => Works OK

But, when the HTTPS server replies with a "302" redirection header, the server name in the header is not translated to the client-side known server name. So, the client fail to connect, due to a DNS error.

We can't add the backend server name in the DNS, so we need that solution to work.

Important notice: the same works in HTTP. It means that when the server reply is a "302" redirection header in HTTP, there's no problem. It works even if the target of the redirection is a HTTPS link. So what is not working is redirecting from HTTPS to HTTPS.
The backend webserver is Tomcat.

The problem is: in HTTPS header, the redirection URL is "https://[backendname]/something.html" but we expect it to be "https://[servername]/something.html"

We've checked that we have no error in log file (error level set to "debug").

Here is our virtual site configuration:

```
<VirtualHost [reverse proxy IP]:443>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile    D:/Apache24/ssl/certs/servername.cer
    SSLCertificateKeyFile D:/Apache24/ssl/private/servername.key

    ServerName [servername]
    ProxyPass / https://[backendname]:443/
        ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / https://[backendname]:443/
        ProxyPassReverse / https://[backendname]:443/

    SetOutputFilter proxy-html
    ProxyHTMLEnable On
    ProxyHTMLURLMap https://[backendname] https://[servername]

    ErrorLog  D:/Apache24/logs/custom/[servername]_error.log
    CustomLog D:/Apache24/logs/custom/[servername]_access.log combined

    SetEnv nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown
</VirtualHost>
```

Problem related Apache activated modules:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule proxy_html_module modules/mod_proxy_html.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule xml2enc_module modules/mod_xml2enc.so
```

So, any help to make this work will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I recently found that my 302 responses were being cached, because Apache was inserting cache-control directives that I didn't want.  I solved my problem with "ExpiresActive Off".

Comment: I've also had similar problems that were solved by adding or removing a leading slash in my redirect urls and/or form action attributes.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working solution, as suggested by Michael Akerman

- disable caching
- write new instruction: ProxyPassReverse https://[backend]/

Thanks for your help